# Share a variable between main and thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, c++11, network-programming

I got a class `MainWindow` that open a `server` function in a `thread` , I need to share a `bool variable` between my main and my thread, I try to use `volatile variable` but it doesn't work, here's the code :

```
//Constructor
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    //Some initialisation
...

    // Constructs the new thread and runs it. Does not block execution.
    bool_Server = true;//Variable supposed to be shared
    m_t1 = std::thread(lancerServeur, bool_Server);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
    bool_Server = false; //Variable supposed to be shared
    m_t1.join();
}


void MainWindow::lancerServeur(bool boolServer){
    serveur s;
    while(boolServer){
        s.receiveDataUDP();//Read data in non blocking mode
    }
}
```

Is the volatile variable shared ?

Comment: You're passing the variable by value. How could it possibly be shared? Use `std::thread(lancerServeur, std::ref(bool_Server))` and make `bool_Server` a `std::atomic<bool>` or use mutexes, etc.

Comment: @Simple someone on the forum told me it works ^^'

Comment: @SimpleDoesn't work, can you put an answer with header and cpp file ?

Comment: @EvansBelloeil _'someone on the forum told me it works ^^''_ Apparently you accepted this answer a bit too quickly, and didn't read all of the comments there. The author of this answer was telling you a few completely wrong things.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're passing a copy of `bool_Server` to `MainWindow::lancerServeur`, so the variable it's observing is not in any way connected to the original `bool_Server`. Making it `volatile` isn't going to help, and `volatile` doesn't make access to an object thread-safe anyway.

You should use an `atomic<bool>` as the flag, and make it a data member of `MainWindow`. There's no need to pass it to `lancerServeur`. Here's a simple example that runs a thread for 5s and then quits.

```
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

struct MainWindow
{
  std::atomic<bool> stop_{false};
  std::thread task_;

  void run()
  {
    while(!stop_) {
      std::cout << "Processing ...\n";
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }

    std::cout << "Stopping ...\n";
  }

  void launch_thread()
  {
    task_ = std::thread(&MainWindow::run, this);
  }

  ~MainWindow()
  {
    stop_ = true;
    task_.join();
  }
};

int main()
{
  {
    MainWindow w;
    w.launch_thread();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the .h file change `bool_Server` to be `std::atomic<bool> bool_Server` and change your .cpp file to be:

```
//Constructor
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    //Some initialisation
...

    // Constructs the new thread and runs it. Does not block execution.
    bool_Server = true;//Variable supposed to be shared
    m_t1 = std::thread(lancerServeur, std::ref(bool_Server));

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
    bool_Server = false; //Variable supposed to be shared
    m_t1.join();
}


void MainWindow::lancerServeur(std::atomic<bool>& boolServer){
    serveur s;
    while(boolServer){
        s.receiveDataUDP();//Read data in non blocking mode
    }
}
```